# mysql retrieve data, for each data append a new row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

i'm doing a project for my school whereby i have to retrieve student works from database.

On my home page, i have preset 10 div to hold the data returned from query. I preset it because i only need to retrieve 10 data.

HTML

```
<div class="viewport-computer col-lg-12 visible-lg no-padding ">
    <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption">Author<br />Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption">Author<br />Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption">Author<br />Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption">Author<br />Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption">Author<br />Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption">Author<br />Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption">Author<br />Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption">Author<br />Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption">Author<br />Description</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then i use jquery to query to my php to get back 10 data and place onto my 10 div

Jquery

```
/* Home Page Autoload featured thumbnails based on computer viewport/mobile viewport
    ================================================== */       
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "CMS/PHP/displayFeatThumbs.php",
            success: function(data) {
                // Display image thumbnail, caption & description of works onto each thumbnail div
                $('.viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder img').each(function(index, element) {
                    // Work out the data to set
                    var imageUrl = "cms/" + data[index].links;
                    var captionHtml = "<span>" + data[index].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + data[index].title + "</span>"
                    // Now apply this to the elements
                    $(element).attr("src", imageUrl); // i must find a way to solve this
                    $(element).parent().css('background-image', 'url("'+imageUrl+'")');
                    $(element).next().html(captionHtml);

                    // push the caption & id into global variable array to be used on other functions easily
                    captionArray.push(data[index].caption);
                    idArray.push(data[index].id);
                    homeLinksArray.push(data[index].links);
                    homeTitleArray.push(data[index].title);
                });
        });
```

It's working fine since i loop through my preset div(10 of them) and then place the data into each div.. Now i need to do a search bar function, and it will return me ALL the results(more than 50), and i have to display all of them, now the problem is that i only preset 10divs, so my workflow is not good for this

so instead of my current

```
loop through 10 div > retrieve data and place on 10 div
```

i would like to

```
retrieve all data, for each data, append a new div and place it
```

i am not very good with php as i'm still a new learner so i'm stuck at this although i have the idea on how to do it. Can someone enlighten me on how i can loop through each data and append instead of my preset divs?

PHP

```
<?php
include 'dbAuthen.php';
$searchBar = $_POST['searchBar']; 
$sql = "SELECT userdatafiles.UserID,Name,Link,Title FROM userdatafiles JOIN users ON userdatafiles.UserID = users.UserID WHERE Skillsets = '$searchBar' GROUP BY UserID ORDER BY RAND()";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);  
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<div>hi</div>',
        $links[] = array(
            "id" => $row["UserID"],
            "links" => $row["Link"],
            "caption" => $row["Name"],
            "title" => $row["Title"],
        );                  
    }
    //shuffle($links);
    echo json_encode($links);   
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is not to preset 50 divs or 10 divs in your UI.

Simply when you retrieve your result loop through all records and at the same time instead of populating your divs you create divs on the fly and insert data to it. When newly created divs are ready append them to your UI with some classes like 'new-data' or something to give a look that these records are somewhat new in your UI.

Assuming data represent your json returned by PHP and data is collection of all records here is one way to do it

```
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
    $('<div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding new-class">'
        +'<img src="'+data[i].imgSrc+'" class="img_thumb">'
        +'<h2 class="caption">'+data[i].author+'<br />'+data[i].description+'</h2>'
        +'</div>').appendTo("ul#yourRecordHolderElemenet").slideDown("fast");
}
```

Exact solution might depend on your json returned by PHP untill you show your exact json response we won't be able to help you properly.

I won't recommend returning data with their html markup being returned from PHP as it would increase amount of data being transferred.

Comment: Thanks bro, all i am looking for is the i<data.length , can't believe i didn't thought of that.. :S

Answer (score 0):

Without writing complete code for you here is a step by step how you could do this

1. Create a database connection with `mysqli` or `pdo`
2. Select all records with a `select` query
3. Do a `foreach` on the resultset
4. Add one `div` in the foreach
5. PHP will add a `div` for each row in the `select` query

for example:

```
 foreach($result->fetch_array() as $row) {
     ?>
     <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption"><?= $row['author'] ?><br /><?= $row['description'] ?></h2>
     </div>
     <?php
 }
```

Comment: i already done 1 & 2, so i do the for each in my php to append a new div each time it found a new matched data selection right?

Comment: @jquerynerd you don't need to use a ajax request to append the data in HTML. You can directly add them to the HTML since data is already there in Database

Comment: can you show me a simple example? Don't have to be based on my question, i want to reference to have a better understanding.. @lepanto

Comment: @jquerynerd hope you would request it, already added a sample as answer

Comment: added a simple example, or check Lepanto's post

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code should be :

```
<?php
include 'dbAuthen.php';
$searchBar = $_POST['searchBar']; 
$sql = "SELECT userdatafiles.UserID,Name,Link,Title FROM userdatafiles JOIN users ON userdatafiles.UserID = users.UserID WHERE Skillsets = '$searchBar' GROUP BY UserID ORDER BY RAND()";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);  
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<div>hi</div>',
        $links = array(
            "id" => $row["UserID"],
            "links" => $row["Link"],
            "caption" => $row["Name"],
            "title" => $row["Title"],
        );                  
    }
    //shuffle($links);
    echo json_encode(array('contents' => $links));   
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

notice single dimension `$link` array and an associative array to `json_encode`.

In jQuery, your `success:` can/will be :

```
success: function(data){
  $.each(data.contents, function(ind, ele){
    // ele.id is the id and etc... or ind.id. :D
  });
}
```

Comment: i know about append. It just that i don't know how to loop through each data that i selected from my database. example search for photography in my database, and it returned me 50 results, i wonder how i can loop through this 50 results and append 50 divs. Ya i know predefine is a bad way.. haha

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the information in database, add them directly in HTML rather than making a ajax request.

```
<div class="viewport-computer col-lg-12 visible-lg no-padding ">
<?php
//You can get 10 records from database using 'limit 10' added to select query. 
//Get data from database. I assume you have the data in a variable $datafromdb

foreach($datafromdb as $data){
?>
    <div class="col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding">
        <img class="img_thumb">
        <h2 class="caption"><?=$data['author']?><br /><?=$data['description']?></h2>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: how does the php know where to place the div into which part of HTML? i'll post my PHP to show u how i retrieve the data. updated post